# Conditionally merging list of Java objects into a map via Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 11 here. I have a `List<Foobar>` as well as a `Map<Foobar,List<String>>`.

I would like to iterate over the list and:

- if the current `Foobar` is a key in the map, and a specific string (*"Can't please everyone"*) to that entry's value list
- if the current `Foobar` is not a key in the map, and it as a new key, with a value that is an `ArrayList` consisting of a single string with the same value

I can accomplish this like so:

```
List<Foobar> foobarList = getSomehow();
Map<Foobar,List<String>> foobarMap = getItSomehow();
String msg = "Can't please everyone";
for (Foobar fb : foobarList) {
    if (foobarMap.containsKey(fb)) {
        foobarMap.get(fb).add(msg);
    } else {
        foobarMap.put(fb, Collections.singletonList(msg));
    }
}
```

This works great, but I'm trying to get this to work using the Java Stream API. My best attempt thus far:

```
List<Foobar> foobarList = getSomehow();
Map<Foobar,List<String>> foobarMap = getItSomehow();
String msg = "Can't please everyone";
foobarList.stream()
    .filter(fb -> foobarMap.containsKey(fb))
        .map(fb -> foobarMap.get(fb).add(msg))
    .filter(fb -> !foobarMap.containsKey(fb))
        .map(fb -> foobarMap.put(fb. Collections.singleton(msg));
```

Yields several compiler errors. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: Why the DV? Not a duplicate, is on topic, is a high quality question and provides enough detail to reproduce and answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are used either

- To modify the contents of the stream elements, or
- To produce another stream from it, or
- To iterate over the elements and do something that doesn't affect the elements of **this** stream.

Since your use case is the last type, the logical operation is simply `forEach(..)`. (I know it is a dampener :-), but that is how the use case is.)

```java
foobarList.forEach( fb -> {
    if (foobarMap.containsKey(fb)) {
        foobarMap.get(fb).add(msg);
    } else {
         foobarMap.put(fb, Collections.singletonList(msg));
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @Sree Kumar, you should use `forEach()`.

However, I would suggest leveraging the `Map.merge()` method:

```
foobarList.forEach(fb -> foobarMap.merge(fb, Collections.singletonList(msg),
        (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).toList()));
```